# I cant extrude (noob question)

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm watching a tuttorial and I am trying to extrude the line between two points by selecting the two points, and hit E. but it looks like that and ı cant go on.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in *Solid View* so you are not able to select the dots behind your view.

To solve this issue go to *Wireframe Mode* by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> and now you can select the dots behind your view, but not with click select the dots with circle tool. The short key is <kbd>C</kbd> .